# Image classifier using CNN models value error

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

hiya so ive been making an image classifier with multiple categories and i keep getting this error

> **ValueError**: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (9,)

idk what im doing wrong with here are my codes this works fine on a 2 category classifier by changin the categorical to binary

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras import backend as K
from PIL import ImageFile, Image
print(Image.__file__)
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 256, 256

train_data_dir = r'C:\Users\Acer\imagerec\Mushrooms\TRAIN'
validation_data_dir = r'C:\Users\Acer\imagerec\Mushrooms\VAL'
nb_train_samples = 6714
nb_validation_samples = 6262
epochs = 20
batch_size = 30

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (1, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 1)

from keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense

vgg = VGG19(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(), pooling='avg')
x = vgg.output
x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(vgg.input, x)
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='Adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import seaborn as sns

test_steps_per_epoch = numpy.math.ceil(validation_generator.samples / validation_generator.batch_size)

predictions = model.predict_generator(validation_generator, steps=test_steps_per_epoch)
# Get most likely class
predicted_classes = numpy.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
true_classes = validation_generator.classes
class_labels = list(validation_generator.class_indices.keys())
report = classification_report(true_classes, predicted_classes, target_names=class_labels)
print(report)

cm=confusion_matrix(true_classes,predicted_classes)

sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True)

print(cm)

plt.show()
```

and here are the errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Acer/PycharmProjects/condas/VGG19.py", line 69, in <module>
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\envs\condas\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\envs\condas\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1732, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\envs\condas\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 220, in fit_generator
    reset_metrics=False)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\envs\condas\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1508, in train_on_batch
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\envs\condas\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 621, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\envs\condas\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 145, in standardize_input_data
    str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (9,)
```

Comment: You have ```Dense(1)``` as last layer it will only work as binary classification, while ```train_data_dir``` might be having more than two classes. Change this to 1 to your number of classes.

Comment: hiya thanks for the reply where exactly should i change it?

Comment: so i changed `x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)` to `x = Dense(9, activation='sigmoid')(x)` same error

Comment: How many classes are there in ```train_data_dir```? Also since you are doing multi-class classification your last dense layer should have activation _softmax_ not _sigmoid_.

Comment: i have 9 classes on my train data dir

Comment: `x = Dense(9, activation='softmax')(x)` still gives me the same error